# Why won't the liquid go up in one "piece"?

Tags: physics, mantaflow

Im trying to make a scene in which the jar is filled up with smoothie but from the bottom. I read online that you can achieve this by simply inverting the gravity so thats what i did. Unfortunately  i did not get the results i wanted. I want the liquid to follow the shape of the jar, not be spit up into these "tentacles". In the video, i hid the jar so only the fluid can be seen (originally at the base). What am i doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am by no means an expert with mantaflow, as I prefer using houdini, however, I don't think gravity manipulation is the right way to go about this. I'm experimenting with your file (thanks for uploading) but I think a better way to go about this is to provide a positive initial velocity on the z axis, an place the emitter within an effector, which acts as a collision (for example a glass) this would mean that the glass would slowly fill up

Comment: I've tried that but its pretty unstable to say the least. It somewhat goes up before the weight of the water crashes down again, causing it to just stay at the bottom. Too high a value and the whole thing just explodes. I find it hard to test as different resolutions would affect the behavior. Have you had any luck with using the velocities?

Comment: From what i've read, this seems to be an on going issue, but I think the best work around is to animate the emitter to move upwards, which will give the illusion of the water filling from the base

Comment: Do you need to simulate liquids here? Smoothies are pretty thick. I might just animate a hidden cube to cut away less and less of the top of a full smoothie with a Boolean.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative workarounds, i think i will give them a shot instead of trying to make this reverse gravity work. Apparently there is a bug where the liquid refuses to rise above level of inflow object.

Comment: Why not rotate the whole scene by 180° and let gravity do its thing... and render it with the camera turned upside down?

Comment: Will be trying that too, thank you